# Css style priority

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am having problems with CSS declaration priority. My page contains an external CSS file with a rule and some inline CSS declarations, which are supposed to override that rule. To my understanding inline style declarations should override external CSS declarations. However, when I view the page in Chrome the second row of the table is displayed blue, when it should be displayed red as defined in the internal style declarations.

What am I missing here

Here is the HTML:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
    <style type="text/css">
        td,tr,th
        {
            background: Red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>22</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>aa</td>
            <td>bb</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the content of the CSS file:

```css
tbody tr:nth-child(even) td,
tbody tr.even td
{
    background: #e5ecf9;
}
```

Comment: You should _avoid_ `!important` - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The number of selectors matters when calculating which rule has the highest specificity.

Two excellent visualizations of CSS specificity are http://www.standardista.com/css3/css-specificity/ and http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html

You should avoid just sticking `!important` on the rule to override (see [What are the implications of using "!important" in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css)) and instead change the selector to give your rule more or equal weight to the imported rule.

For example the following will make all cells `background:red`

```
thead tr:nth-child(1n) th, tbody tr:nth-child(1n) td {
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: @Raisch yes thanks. Spotted that, was just testing the correct selector locally :-)

Answer (score 2):

In this case the more detailed rule will get it.

Try this in your HTML:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
    tbody tr:nth-child(even) td,
    tbody tr:nth-child(even) tr,
    tbody tr:nth-child(even) th
    {
        background: Red;
    }
</style>
```

Best regards

Comment: The code is misleading, because the part `,tr,th` has no impact and its role can easily be misunderstood. What matters here is the setting on certain `td` elements using sufficiently large specificity.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - I know, i just extended his own CSS block. :-)

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela updated my answer over 6 years later! :-)