# CSS rules order in the same style sheet

Tags: css

A CSS rule overrides the rules that come before it in the style sheet. That is why the color displayed is red in the following example.

```css
.two {
    background-color: blue;
}

.two {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
    Hello
    <div class="two"> World! </div>
</div>
```

Why in the next example the color is blue?

```css
.one .two {
    background-color: blue;
}

.two {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
    Hello
    <div class="two"> World! </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Css style priority](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088007/css-style-priority)

Comment: See https://specificity.keegan.st/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thats because of

```
.one .two {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

It takes a higher precedence since it has 2 class selectors `.one` and `.two` so it's more specific as compared to the second with just `.two`

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because the code:

```
.one .two {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

targets the child of `class` - one, whereas

```
.two {
   background-color: red;
}
```

targets the `class` - two only which is parent.

Since the precedence of the style applied to `child` is higher than that of its parent, so it gets applied that style on the child element.