# Do external stylesheets lower down in .css file override previous ones?

Tags: html, css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css2.css">
```

imagine in the first stylesheet is says h1 color blue. Imagine the second stylesheet says h1 color red. Which one wins?

Comment: did you try it? you could have just test it locally.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Css style priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088007/css-style-priority)

Comment: You're right could've just tried it. The second stylesheet overrules. Would delete question but it advises against it.

Answer (score 0):

there exists an order for style sheets according to their priority

```
Browser Defaults
External Style Sheets (Linked or Imported)
Internal Style Sheets (Embedded)
Inline Styles
```

In any of the methods, if the same style names are used, the last priority is higher than all the same names

Answer (score -1):

I'm actually not sure, what happens if two css have the same name. I would assume it doesn't matter.

What does matter for sure is the order of css files. Files, which are included later have a higher priority in case of same selectors. So yes, the second one would win.

More important is even the selector. If a selector is more specific than another one, the more specific wins. E.g. `body h1` is more specific than `h1` and would win - even if included before the `h1`.

The only way to go around that, is to find either a more specific selector - or the same specific selector if included later - or to use `!important`.